# Parsing Last Name from Name in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to determine a single last name.

```
names = ["John Smith", "D.J. Richies III","AJ Hardie Jr.", "Shelia Jackson-Lee", "Bob O'Donnell"]
```

Desired Output

```
last_names = ['Smith', 'Richies','Hardie','Lee', 'ODonnell' ]
```

I'm hoping there is an existing library or set of code that can easily handle some of these more rare/odd cases.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Asking people to recommend libraries is generally not considered an appropriate question to SO. What have you tried? It looks like you just need to take the second word after a `str.split()` and remove punctuation, this is pretty simple to do with the standard string functions.

Comment: The problem comes with hyphenated names.  I understand what you mean though as then it could be two splits (2nd to cover hyphenated  names) and then a compact.  

Just didn't know if there was a library that everyone used that I had no idea existed (fairly new to Python).

Comment: Also what if you have middle names? Or last names that are two tokens without a hyphen?

Comment: Actually, a library is a good ask here. Dealing with names in applications is harder than most people realize, and I wouldn't be surprised if someone had put together something like this into a library.

Comment: I don't think there are middle names as these names are scraped from a website.  I don't have every example but after looking at a few hundred it seems that there are none, which is why I think AChampion's solution might work.

Comment: That solution will eventually fail. Maybe not for you and your specific case, but SO is for other people too.

Comment: Just want to give a shoutout to: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: BTW - Your sample output removes the apostrophe from `O'Donnell`. That's not a good practice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Dealing with Names is Hard

Naive string-manipulation solutions will eventually fail. You start to realize this with suffixes (`III`, `Jr.`), but what about compound last names like `de la Paz`?

You want:
[The Python Human Name Parser](http://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
>>> from nameparser import HumanName
>>> name = HumanName("Dr. Juan Q. Xavier de la Vega III")
>>> name.title
'Dr.'
>>> name["title"]
'Dr.'
>>> name.first
'Juan'
>>> name.middle
'Q. Xavier'
>>> name.last
'de la Vega'
>>> name.suffix
'III'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
names = ["John Smith", "D.J. Richies III","AJ Hardie Jr.", "Shelia Jackson-Lee", "Bob O'Donnell"]

suffixes = ["II", "Jr.", "III", "Sr."]

last_names = []

for i in names:
    new_name = i.split()
    if len(new_name) == 2 and "-" in new_name[1]:
         last_names.append(new_name[1].split("-")[1])

    elif len(new_name) == 2:
          last_names.append(new_name[1])

    else:
        if new_name[-1] in suffixes:
           last_names.append(new_name[1])

print(last_names)
```

Output will contain the last names:

```
['Smith', 'Richies', 'Hardie', 'Lee', "O'Donnell"]
```

Comment: This could be combined with a list of suffixes to strip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **nameparser** package. For more examples you can have a look at the [link](https://predictivehacks.com/name-parser-with-python/):

```
from nameparser import HumanName
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ["John Smith", "D.J. Richies III","AJ Hardie Jr.", "Shelia Jackson-Lee", "Bob O'Donnell"]})

df["title"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: HumanName(x).title)
df["first"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: HumanName(x).first)
df["middle"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: HumanName(x).middle)
df["last"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: HumanName(x).last)
df["suffix"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: HumanName(x).suffix)
df["nickname"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: HumanName(x).nickname)
df
```

And the output is:

```
                 Name title   first middle         last suffix nickname
0          John Smith          John               Smith                
1    D.J. Richies III          D.J.             Richies    III         
2       AJ Hardie Jr.            AJ              Hardie    Jr.         
3  Shelia Jackson-Lee        Shelia         Jackson-Lee                
4       Bob O'Donnell           Bob           O'Donnell
```

So if you want only the surnames:

```
df['last']
```

And you get:

```
0          Smith
1        Richies
2         Hardie
3    Jackson-Lee
4      O'Donnell
Name: last, dtype: object
```